# why web api(RestFul) .NetCore service is not accepting forward slash in parameters, how to resolve this issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, forward, slash

I am using webApi(RESTFUL service) and Angular as front end. I need to call one end point and my parameters has "forward slash"(/). I am encoding parameter string and calling endpoint. but my webApi giving handler error "URL" not found. could you please tell me how I need to fix this one.

my url: https://localhost:44356/api/v1/sample/sampleget/Arts%2Fscience%20course/All

Encoded string: Arts%2Fscience%20course
original string: Arts/science course

could any one please help me , how I need to resolve the problem in Angular/ webApi

Comment: I just included * in webApi attribute routing in front of parameter, it worked. In web api: [Route("sampleget/{parameter1}/{*parameter2}")]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send a string which has `/` (slashes) in it, we can use the `wildcard parameters` in the route. Something like this:

`Route("sampleget/{*course}")`

This will allow for a chunk of a URL with multiple `/` characters to be read as a single parameter.

Hope it helps.